# jqplot - Ticks and labels overlap in salesforce page

Tags: jquery, salesforce, jqplot

I was wondering how come implementing `jqplot` in Salesforce, ticks and labels overlap. Just like this:

[image]

I tried adjusting everything but still, no luck. 
It won't even rotate the label when i tried rotating it. 
This is how I did it:

```
function renderGraph(){

        //Days of the month
        var dayTicks = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],
                        [10,10],[11,11],[12,12],[13,13],[14,14],[15,15],[16,16],[17,17],[18,18],[19,19],
                        [20,20],[21,21],[22,22],[23,23],[24,24],[25,25],[26,26],[27,27],[28,28],[29,29],
                        [30,30],[31,31],[32,""]];

        apiGraph = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[1,363],[3,1122],[6,710]],{
                        seriesDefaults  : { pointLabels: { show:true }},                
                        axesDefaults    : { labelRenderer   : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                                            tickRenderer    : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                                            showTicks       : true  },
                        axes: {
                                xaxis: {
                                        label: 'Days',
                                        ticks:dayTicks
                                },
                                yaxis: {
                                    tickOptions : {
                                                    labelPosition: 'middle', 
                                                    angle:-30},
                                        pad: 1.0, 
                                        label: 'Student',
                                        min: 0,
                                        max:10000
                                }
                        }});
    }
```

I've just learning jqplot Im not really familiar with all options.
At what point could have done wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the entire code(for the graph part). How you are plotting the graph. Also the data part, print the data and hardcode it.

Comment: @AnishNair i updated the source code for the graph part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a fiddle for the snippet that you posted.
And it works fine for me.

I think you are missing the necessary jqPlot files.

Make sure you are including the necessary files in the `<script>` tag

Here's the list of files to be included. Have you included these files in your code?

1. Jquery JS file
2. jquery.jqplot.min.js (jqPLot JS File)
3. jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js
4. jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js
5. jquery.jqplot.min.css (jqPLot CSS File)

Here's the link to the fiddle : [JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/tb4e2k5o/)

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Hi @elL
What fixed it? Were you missing the necessary files?